# Problem updating JPanel in JDialog with JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcombobox, jdialog

I have created a JDialog which contains a JComboBox and a panel underneath which should display a different content based on the value selected in the JComboBox. I have created a JPanel (panel_1) which is added to the content pane of the dialog and an additional JPanel for each of the possible items in the JComboBox (for example panel_item_1 and panel_item_2 if it does have only 2 items). I have attached the following listener class in the JComboBox:

```
public class SelectedListener implements ActionListener {

private SettingsDialog dialog;

public SelectedListener(SettingsDialog dialog){

    this.dialog = dialog;

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

   JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
       String selected_settings = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();

       if(selected_settings.compareTo("Option 1") == 0){

        dialog.panel_1 = dialog.panel_item_1;
        dialog.panel_1.updateUI();

    }else if(selected_settings.compareTo("Option 2") == 0 ){

        dialog.panel_1 = dialog.panel_item_2;
        dialog.panel_1.updateUI();

    }

}
```

}

However this doesn't make the panel update with the new content. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: How about using `validate()` instead of `updateUI()` ?

Comment: never-never-ever call updateUI in application code to "update" anything, the method is _exclusively_ for usage by LAF

Comment: me blind, or is the condition the exact same in if and else-if?

Comment: yes, kleopatra, it was a mistake, but changing that still doesn't solve the issue

Comment: didn't say it would - Rob (@camickr) spotted the real problem ;-) and remove those updateUI calls - the _never_ help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> which should display a different content based on the value selected in the JComboBox.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Card Layout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) which has a working example that does exactly what you want.

Edit:

```
dialog.panel_1 = dialog.panel_item_1;
```

The real problem is that you can't just change the reference to a variable and expect the component to show up on the panel. You still need to add the component to the panel before you do a revalidate() on the panel. So your code is like:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

However, the better solution is to use a CardLayout which does all this work for you.